# jquery ui autocomplete filtering on label only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery v1.10.2 and i have following code:

```
(function() {
  var manufacturers=[];
  manufacturers.push({
    label:'Ismail Mayat',
    value:'Ismail Mayat info@test.com'
  });
  $('#list').autocomplete({
        source: manufacturers
      }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      var term = $('#list').val();
      var label = item.label.replace(new RegExp(term, 'i'), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');

      return $( '<li></li>' )
        .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
        .append( '<a>' + label + '</a>' )
        .appendTo( ul );
  };

})();
```

when i search for ismail or mayat i get match. However when i search for info i get no results.  If i move the info part to the label then it works.  Does the filter regex only use the label for search?  I also tried to over ride the regex by adding code:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp('(^| )' + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), 'i');
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

but i still get the same thing. Am i missing a trick here?

Regards

Ismail

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it. So i need to over ride the filter to:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp('(^| )' + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), 'i');
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label) || matcher.test(value.value) || matcher.test(value);
    });
};
```

that works.